# Find mean median mode from text file java

Tags: java

I have a text file called numbers.txt and its full of numbers. I need to find the mean median and mode of the numbers. I can read the file but I don't know any more than that.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Terms {


    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

        File file = 
      new File("C:\\Users\\coderva.org\\Documents\\numbers.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
      System.out.println(sc.nextLine());  



}
}
```

Comment: show us your code. what issues are you facing?

Comment: we're going to need more details than just "I can read the file". Are you having trouble extracting numbers from the text file?

Comment: this is my code. I know how to read the file but Im not sure how to extract numbers

Comment: @NoahCrone don't post the code in the comments. Edit your question and paste it there

Comment: `sc.nextLine()` reads the line of the file as a String - check the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for reading as numeric values - for example `nextLong()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the definitions of mean, median and mode:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\coderva.org\\Documents\\numbers.txt");

    Scanner sc = null;

    try {
        sc = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    ArrayList<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();

    while (sc.hasNextFloat())
        list.add(sc.nextFloat());

    int size = list.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        System.out.println("Empty list");
        return;
    }

    Collections.sort(list);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();

    // mean value, classical way
    float sum = 0;
    for (float x : list) {
        sum += x;
    }

    float mean = sum / size; // mean as integer

    //median
    float median;

    if (size % 2 == 0) {
        float x1 = list.get(size / 2 - 1);
        float x2 = list.get(size / 2);
        median = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    } else {
        median = list.get(size / 2);
    }

    //mode
    Float mode = null;
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int freq = Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i));
        if (freq > counter) {
            mode = list.get(i);
            counter = freq;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Mean=" + mean);

    System.out.println("Median=" + median);

    if (mode == null) {
        System.out.println("No mode found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Mode=" + mode);
    }
}
```

Comment: the code you posted just prints "Empty List".  Based on the code it looks like that would be because the file size is 0 but I don't understand why it would think the size is 0? could you explain that

Comment: Does your text file contain 1 integer number in each row?

Comment: The text file is a list of 10,000 decimal numbers with one number per line.

Comment: So they are not integers?

Comment: did you just edit the existing code posted or is there a new post?

Comment: I edited the existing post. As you can see all the declarations are now `float`

Comment: Thank you  so much

Comment: do I just click the check mark? sorry I'm new to stack overflow

Comment: Yes you did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of numbers as such:

```
List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
while (sc.hasNextInt()) 
  numberList.add(sc.nextInt());
```

Or when you have doubles or floats:

```
List<Double> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
while (sc.hasNextDouble()) 
  numberList.add(sc.nextDouble()); 

List<Float> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
while (sc.hasNextFloat()) 
  numberList.add(sc.nextFloat());
```

From there you can calculate the mean as follows:

```
sum = numberList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
average = sum / numberList.size();
```

And so on for the other properties you need.

**Note** The types are of sum and average are depended on which types you read from the file.